# Drupal 8 optional in drupal_process_states doesn't work

Tags: forms, field, conditional-statements, drupal-8

I've defined few conditional fields with [drupal_process_states](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/8.2.x) that should only be displayed and validated if radio button has value 'post'. It works for 'invisible' and 'disabled' properties, but it does not work for 'optional' property. It allows to submit a form, but it fails on backend validation saying that those fields are required. Here is my code in form alter hook:

```
$states_when_delivery_is_post = array(
    'disabled' => array(
        ':input[name="field_delivery_way"]' => array('value' => 'email'),
    ),
    'optional' => array(
        ':input[name="field_delivery_way"]' => array('value' => 'email'),
    ),
    'invisible' => array(
        ':input[name="field_delivery_way"]' => array('value' => 'email'),
    ),
);

if (isset($form['field_country'])) {
  $form['field_country']['#states'] = $states_when_delivery_is_post;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, states only provide front-end functionality, so you should implement backend rules by yourself. For example I don't need address fields to be required if delivery way is email, so I'm clearing those address fields errors:

```
function module_name_form_name_validation(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    if ($form_state->getValue('field_delivery_way')[0]['value'] == 'email') {
        $errors = $form_state->getErrors();
        $conditional_fields = ['field_city][0][value', 'field_house_number][0][value', 'field_postcode][0][value', 'field_street][0][value', 'field_country'];
        $form_state->clearErrors();
        foreach ($errors as $element => $error) {
            if (!in_array($element, $conditional_fields)) {
                $form_state->setErrorByName($element, $error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```